# call shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation but lock view from rotating

Tags: ios

I want to create a UIVIew that will not rotate when I will call to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation , and other subviews will rotate.

and i want to keep the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation suppot, and not use notification.

thanks

Comment: can you show me some code how to prevent from uiview to rotate? do you mean by orverride the draw method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to define exactly what you mean by having a view "not rotate" when the device is rotated.  Rotation can mean several things, depending on which coordinate system to which you refer.  A better way to think about it is simply, what do you want your view to look like for each device orientation.

Just to remind, shouldAutorotateTo... is sent to your view controller by the system.  You don't invoke it yourself.  It doesn't cause rotation.  It lets the system ask your view controller what orientations it supports.

Your VC should answer YES for all orientations it supports.  A supported orientation is one where the view changes layout in response to a device orientation change, so if any layout change occurs for a given orientation, then the answer to shouldAutorotateTo is probably YES.

Altering subview layout for a given interface orientation is mostly your responsibility.   Views have an autoresizingMask which is a bit vector describing some options for sizing and positioning relative to their parent, and this is often adequate.  The way to fully control layout on orientation change is by implementing willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation.

For example, here's a fairly permissive shouldAutorotate, enabling all but one orientation...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

And here's how you would control how subviews layout on rotation...

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    UIView *testView = [self.view viewWithTag:16];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        // change frames here to make the ui appear according to your spec
        // including however you define "not rotating" for each view
        self.subviewA.frame = .....
        self.subviewB.frame = .....                
    } else {
        self.subviewA.frame = .....
        self.subviewB.frame = .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one UIView not to Rotate with orientation, one of the easy solution is to add that view to Application top Window like this. Because window dont rotate with device orientations.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]windows]objectAtIndex:0]addSubview:customView];
```